# Defining new schema for Spark Rows

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame and one of its columns contains a string of JSON. So far, I've implemented the `Function` interface as required by the `JavaRDD.map` method: `Function<Row,Row>()`. Within this function, I'm parsing the JSON, and creating a new row whose additional columns came from values in the JSON. For example:

Original row:

```
+------+-----------------------------------+
|  id  |        json                       |
+------+-----------------------------------+
|  1   | {"id":"abcd", "name":"dmux",...}  |
+------------------------------------------+
```

After applying my function:

```
+------+----------+-----------+
|  id  | json_id  | json_name |
+------+----------+-----------+
|  1   | abcd     | dmux      |
+-----------------+-----------+
```

I'm running into trouble when trying to create a new DataFrame from the returned JavaRDD. Now that I have these new rows, I need to create a schema. The schema is highly dependent on the structure of the JSON, so I'm trying to figure out a way of passing schema data back from the function along with the `Row` object. I can't use `broadcast` variables as the SparkContext doesn't get passed into the function.

Other than looping through each column in a row in the caller of `Function` what options do I have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `StructType`. This is `Scala`, but it would work the same way:

```
val newSchema = StructType(Array(
  StructField("id", LongType, false),
  StructField("json_id", StringType, false),
  StructField("json_name", StringType, false)
))

val newDf = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, newSchema)
```

Incidentally, you need to make sure your `rdd` is of type `RDD[Row]`.

Comment: David, I'm currently using StructType in the caller method, but I don't know what additional StructFields will be in my JSON.

Comment: Is the `JSON` schema the same from row to row? It had better be or else you can't do what you want.

Comment: It's the same for each row, but could differ from dataframe to dataframe.

Comment: So then you just need to build your `StructType` dynamically based on the `JSON` schema. Since `StructType` takes an `Array` of `StructField`, just map your `JSON` columns to an `Array` of `StructField` and pass that to the constructor of `StructType`

Comment: Hi David, the mapping itself takes place in the implementation of the function method. (https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/function/Function.html). Unless you mean perform an initial parse of the JSON before "exploding" it into separate columns.

Comment: You will need the `JSON` structure outside of the mapping -- either before or after you create the `JavaRDD` -- but regardless, you have to create the `StructType` outside of the context of processing your `RDD`

Comment: How can do the same in Java.